# Building multi-container docker-compose fails to build frontend

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, digital-ocean, mern

this is my first time deploying a MERN stack application using docker-compose. The backend (Express Server & MongoDB) is working well. I can post data with Postman and fetch data successfully. But my React app with NGINX conf proxy is returning an error during build.

```
production_frontend_1 exited with code 127
frontend_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 38: yarn: not found
frontend_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 38: yarn: not found
```

Here's my React Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.2 as build
# RUN npm install -g yarn
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY package*.json ./
RUN  yarn install && yarn cache clean
COPY . /app
ARG SERVER_APP_API
ARG SERVER_REST_API
ENV SERVER_REST_API ${SERVER_REST_API:-http://localhost:7000/api/v1/}
RUN SERVER_REST_API=${SERVER_REST_API} yarn run build
# ------------------------------------------------------
# Production Build
# ------------------------------------------------------
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here's my NGINX.conf

```
server { 
 listen 80;
 server_name localhost;

 location / {
    # This would be the directory where your React app's static files are stored at
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - developer-tier
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: npm run start
    env_file: ./backend/.env
    environment:
      - CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3001/
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DATABASE_URL=mongodb://db:27017/developer
      
  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - backend
    env_file: ./frontend/.env
    networks:
      - developer-tier
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/frontend/src/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: yarn start

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    networks:
      - developer-tier
    volumes:
      - dev-data:/data/db

volumes:
  dev-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  developer-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: you commented out your installation of yarn? in line 2 `# RUN npm install -g yarn`, just remove the `#`, or you can just npm for that?

Comment: ```npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/yarn'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/yarn

ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g yarn' returned a non-zero code: 239```

Comment: @Jerryc I get this above error on build when I uncomment the ```# RUN npm install -g yarn```

Comment: looks like yarn comes with the node image, not sure about it.

Comment: @Jerryc I get this above error on build when I uncomment the ```# RUN npm install -g yarn```. When I revert back, it builds successfully with ```exited with code 127```